# get Text property from an entity in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I store some large text data into the google app engine datastore as a Text object using `entityName.setProperty("textProperty", text)` 
where "text" is a Text type object. When I try to fetch the text, I use `entityName.getProperty("textProperty");` 
Since it returns an object and I store it as a Text object, I just cast it to Text using `(Text)entityName.getProperty("textProperty");` 
But it gives me `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text` 
So it looks like the application stores it as a String, so I do `(String)entityName.getProperty("textProperty");` 
But it gives me this 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

I am getting confused: how can I get the Text object from the datastore?

Comment: Can I take it that you have now resolved this issue? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: If you have now resolved this issue, perhaps you should answer this post to close it?

Comment: Can you post how did you resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I use `Text text = new Text(String);` to cast from string to text, and   `String s = text.getValue();` to cast from text to string.

Comment: Of course, what you mention above is not strictly casting in the sense of `Text text = (Text)object;` but using a `Text` constructor and method to generate one type of object from the other.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to resolve my issue while mapping TextProperty with JPA in Google APP Engine.

I defined a Text property content, Whenever I do a Set: I will pass Text. Whenever I do a Get, I will return a String by using the getValue() method.  It works for mine.

```
@Column(name="content")
private Text content;
public void setContent(Text content) {
    this.content = content;
}
public String getContent() {
    return content.getValue();
}
```